# showing one of 3 divs depending on which select is chosen

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a select box with 3 option body, strength, distance.  I want to use javascript / jquery to show a div depending on which of those options is selected. so far I have just got it working on a button push http://codepen.io/Irish1/pen/iwKam

#### html

```
<form>
  <p>
    <label for="select">
      Goal Type
    </label>
    <select class="typeselect">
      <option value=""></option>
      <option value="body">
        Body
      </option>
      <option value="strength">
        Strength
      </option>
      <option value="distance">
        Distance
      </option>
    </select>
    <button class="toggle">push</button>
  </p>
  <div class="body">
    <p>
      <label for="body">
       Body
      </label>
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="strength">
    <p>
      <label for="strength">
        Strength
      </label>
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="distance">
    <p>
      <label for="distance">
       Distance
      </label>
    </p>
  </div>


</form>
```

#### css

```
.body {
  display: none;
}

.strength {
  display: none;
}

.distance {
  display: none;
}
```

#### javascript

```
$('.toggle').click(function(){
  $('.body').toggle();
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
//dom ready handler
jQuery(function () {
    //all the elements that has to be shown/hidden, it is cached for easy access later
    var $targets = $('.body, .strength, .distance');

    //chang handler for the select element
    $('.typeselect').change(function () {
        //hide previously displayed elements
        $targets.hide()

        //find the element with the selected option's value as class, if empty option is selected set it to an empty set
        if (this.value) {
            $('.' + this.value).show()
        }
    })
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/AyN9V)

If you want to make the button handler work then

```
//dom ready handler
jQuery(function () {
    //all the elements that has to be shown/hidden, it is cached for easy access later
    var $targets = $('.body, .strength, .distance');

    var $select = $('.typeselect');

    //click handler for the button
    $('.toggle').click(function (e) {
        //prevent the default form action of the button click
        e.preventDefault();

        //hide previously displayed elements
        $targets.hide()

        //selected value
        var val = $select.val();
        //find the element with the selected option's value as class, if empty option is selected set it to an empty set
        if (val) {
            $('.' + val).show()
        }
    })
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/vp5Sa/)

Comment: Arun's does a similar thing to what I threw together for you: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ktesh

Comment: @michaelt sorry... what did you mean

Comment: I forked @Irish's original code, made a few minor modifications, and have a working example:  http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ktesh  

Only a few lines of jQuery and really minor mods to the dom.

Comment: @michaelt the only problem is when you select the empty option it will throw an error... handle that too then it is fine... but I will suggest you to cache the value of the selector `('.target')`

Comment: I'd even so so far as to remove the empty <option> tag altogether.  Instructions really belong in a <label> tag.

Comment: @michaelt if the OP wants to give an option to select none then it has to be there

Comment: Sure. If the OP wants to do that, by all means. There's always other means of achieving the same end.

Answer (score 3):

```
$('#typeselect').change(function(event) {
   $('.target').hide();
   var option = $(this).val();
   if (option != "") $('.'+option).show();
});
```

and a few minor mods to the html

```
<form>
  <p>
    <label for="select">Goal Type</label>
    <select id="typeselect" class="typeselect">
      <option value=""></option>
      <option value="body">Body</option>
      <option value="strength">Strength</option>
      <option value="distance">Distance</option>
    </select>
  </p>
  <div class="body target">
    <p><label for="body">Body</label></p>
  </div>
  <div class="strength target">
    <p><label for="strength">Strength</label></p>
  </div>
  <div class="distance target">
    <p><label for="distance">Distance</label></p>
  </div> 
</form>
```

You can view and edit here at codepen:  http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ktesh

Comment: can you make the corrections I updated in my comments

Comment: what corrections would that be?

Comment: I'm assuming you meant the blank option tag.  I've added in a condition to test the value coming from the option.  If it's not blank it'll show the corresponding <div>

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('.typeselect').change(function(){
   $('div').hide();
   if($(this).val() == ""){
      $(this).children('option:first-child').show();
   }
   else
      $('.' + $(this).val()).show();
});
```

Comment: it is not `$(this).value` either `$(this).val()` or `this.value`

Comment: Sorry about that! I have a confusion with javascript

Comment: again it will throw an error if the empty option is selected

Comment: I think the option("" in this case) is selected by default. So I'll modify for this.

Answer (score 0):

Give a name / Id to Select and Div's.

```
var x = document.getElementById("SelectId / Name").selected;

    if(x==0) {
        document.getElementById("body").style.display = "block";
    } else {
        \\ Similarly for other div to display on the basis of x
    }
```